# Bootstrap not working with Symfony

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

[this is the code base.html.twig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v5cD.png) Here's my code where i put the bootstrap.min.css and font-awesome.min.css
Ive just started to work with symfony and trying to add some nav bar with bootstrap in my page and its not working, its just a trial there is no javascript in it

Comment: Are you sure that `*.css` exists in `web/css` directory ?

Comment: yes it does. I just checked

Answer (score 2):

I notice your Apache DocumentRoot is wrong. You need to specify the "web" folder, not the higher level "Symfony" folder (I can see in your screenshot).

This "might" cause the path problems, I'm not certain.
Edit the "httpd.conf" Apache config file using the correct path:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/.../Symfony/web"
...
<Directory "C:/.../Symfony/web">
...
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
...
    AllowOverride All
...
</Directory>
```

I'm not sure the exact path so I show `C:/.../Symfony/web`.
Let me know if there are problems.

**EDIT #2**
Based on your screenshot, you'll need to read up on templates and inheritance in twig:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html#including-stylesheets-and-javascripts-in-twig

That most likely is the problem. I see problems with you base file, too much to go into...

Comment: Was that the problem Samar? If so can you also click the checkmark by my answer - that way when people search on Stackoverflow and see your question, they will know this is a working solution.

Comment: Ive just edited the 'httpd.conf" and it not quite working anyhow. the Font-Awesome.min.css is working though but its not the case for bootstrap.min.css

Comment: I hope there is an explanation

Comment: Samar: Can you please edit your post and show the twig file you use for your controller and in specific the block section for your Javascripts. I suspect you've made an error there.

Comment: <?php

namespace SZ\InternshipBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('SZInternshipBundle:Default:index.html.twig');
    }
}

Comment: No, I need the contents of this file:  SZInternshipBundle:Default:index.html.twig

Comment: {% extends  '::base.html.twig'%}

Comment: Then I need the content of: base.html.twig

Comment: Its in the picture i guess.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - My App</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{   asset('css/bootsrap.min.css') }}"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{   asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}"/>

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{  asset('css/add.css')}}" />

        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block nav %}{% include '::nav.html.twig' %}{% endblock %}
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bootsrap.min.js') }}"></script>

    </body>
</html>

Comment: I edited my post. You need to read up on templating. Post another (separate) question if you still have problems. It should be an easy fix.